# Packages are not being installed in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install fipy in anaconda (after doing `conda init bash`) and it seems like I cannot install anything at all using the conda install command:
`conda install -c conda-forge fipy` 
I am getting the following error:

```
 # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
        module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .install import install
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 21, in <module>
        from ..core.solve import DepsModifier, Solver
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 14, in <module>
        from .link import PrefixSetup, UnlinkLinkTransaction
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 43, in <module>
        from ..resolve import MatchSpec
      File "/home/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 9, in <module>
        from tqdm import tqdm
    ImportError: No module named tqdm

`$ /home/<username>/anaconda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge fipy`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
          COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/<username>/anaconda/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/<username>/anaconda
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/<username>/anaconda/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/<username>/anaconda
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/<username>/anaconda/bin:/home/<username>/anaconda/bin:/home/debsan
                          kar/anaconda/condabin:/home/<username>/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/us
                          r/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
                          /snap/bin:/home/<username>/anaconda/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/<username>/anaconda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/<username>/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/<username>/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 2.7.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=9.0
                          __glibc=2.23
       base environment : /home/<username>/anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/<username>/anaconda/pkgs
                          /home/<username>/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/<username>/anaconda/envs
                          /home/<username>/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.10.0 CPython/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.0-210-generic ubuntu/16.04.7 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: y
```

Even the report did not go through:

```
Upload did not complete.
Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true
```

I have tried to find existing solutions but could not understand which one will apply to my case. Any hint is welcome!

Comment: It shows that Anaconda **base** environment is using Python v2.7, which is no longer supported. If you have had this installed for a long time, then you could attempt upgrading Python in the **base** environment (`conda install -n base python=3.9`), but be sure to verify that the `conda` package also upgrades. Otherwise, if this is a new installation, please remove and install a newer version, and perhaps consider [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) instead of Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Thank you @merv! But ```conda install -n base python=3.9``` is producing the same error. It feels like it cannot connect to the internet.. My desktop has a old ubuntu version 16.04, probably it has something to do with that?

Comment: Okay, I removed old anaconda and installed the new anaconda3 which is working fine but cannot install fipy. I will add a different question on that.